# sudo rm -rf /* is not working

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, sudo, rm

Using an online Arch-linux emulator, I ran `sudo rm -rf /*` and this is what I got:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo rm -rf /*
_(blicking)
```

And I got a lot of "rm: operation not permitted"
The question is I an login as root so why the operation is not permitted?

Comment: Why are you using **sudo** when you are already logged in as root?

Comment: Try `find / -xdev -delete` to remove all files from the root filesystem (and still brick your system beyond repair!). `rm -rf /*` would fail to remove hidden files in `/` and would also try to remove files in different file  systems mounted under `/` (and of course every filesystem is mounted under `/`), including virtual ones such as /proc, /sys where removing files doesn't make sense and is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to remove all files and directories from the system.

This includes `/proc` and `/sys`, which are virtual filesystems provided by the kernel and contain files that cannot be deleted.

---

As [an aside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762366/sudo-rm-rf-is-not-working/762367#comment1454316_762366) there is no need to use `sudo` to become root when you are already root

Comment: Actually since `sudo` is *switch user do* and the default target user when not specified with `-u` depends on the configuration (though by default it tends to be `root`), using `sudo` could actually end up dropping super-user privileges.